# using multiple class for triangle program

Tags: java, class, methods, geometry

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Triangle {
// inputing the intgers of the triangle
public void inputTriangleSides()
{
    System.out.println("Enter your triangle side lengths");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int side1; 
    int side2; 
    int side3;
    System.out.println("Enter three integers to form a triangle:");
    side1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    side2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    side3 = keyboard.nextInt();
}
// determines if the three number make a triangle
public void ifTriangle (int side1, int side2, int side3)
{
    if (side1+side2> side3 && side1+side3>side2 && side2+side3>side1)
    {
        System.out.println("it a triangle");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Not a Triangle");
    }
}
// sorts the numbers from lowest to highest
public static void displaySortedNumbers(int side1, int side2,  int side3 ){
    if ((side1 < side2) && (side2 < side3) &&(side1 <side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side1 + " " + side2 + " " + side3);
    }
    if ((side1 < side2) && (side2 > side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side1 + " " + side3 + " " + side2);
    }
    if ((side1 > side2) && (side2 > side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side3 + " " + side2 + " " + side1);
    }
    if ((side1 < side2) && (side2 > side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side3 + " " + side1 + " " + side2);
    }
    if ((side1 > side2) && (side2 > side3) && (side1>side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side2 + " " + side3 + " " + side1);
    }
    if ((side1 > side2) && (side2 < side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side2 + " " + side1 + " " + side3);
    }
}

//determines the type of triangle the three intgers form
public void displayType(int side1, int side2,int side3)
{
    if(( side1+side2 > side3))

        if(( side1==side2) && (side2==side3))//tell if equalateral
        {
            System.out.println("Equalateral Triangle.");
        }
        else if (( side1==side2) & (side2 != side3) || (side1 == side3) & (side3 !=side1))//tells if isosceles
        {
            System.out.println ("Isosceles Triangle.");
        }
        else if ((side1 != side2) & (side2 != side3))//tells if scalene
        {
            System.out.println("Scalene Triangle.");        
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not a triangle");
    }

}//missing return statement
// determines the perimeter
public int perimeter (int side1,int side2, int side3)
{
    if (side1+side2> side3 && side1+side3>side2 && side2+side3>side1)
    {
        int perimeter= side1+side2+side3;
        return perimeter;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

im trying to transfer the methods in this code to another which is this one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TriangleDriver {
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Triangle yourTriangle= new Triangle();
    yourTriangle.inputTriangleSides();
    yourTriangle.displaySortedNumbers();
    yourTriangle.displayType();
    yourTriangle.perimeter();
}
}
```

Im getting an error for displayedSortedNumber part of the code.Method displaySortedNumber in class Triangle cannot be applied to given types; required int, int, int; found no arguements reason: actual and formal arguement list differ in length. How would I fix this? I'm trying get an output where you input three number and it will sort the numbers, see if they make a triangle, what type it is and get the perimeter.

Comment: 1)now, the displaySortedNumbers(); method takes 3 arguments. (you're calling it without any) 2)maybe those three arguments should be attributes in your Triangle class and be removed from the method signature.

Answer (score 2):

Call the displaySortedNumbers method from the inputTriangleSides method.
your main function will be like this

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   Triangle yourTriangle= new Triangle();
   yourTriangle.inputTriangleSides();
 }
```

And your input triangles method will be like this

```
  public void inputTriangleSides()
    {
       System.out.println("Enter your triangle side lengths");
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       int side1; 
       int side2; 
       int side3;
       System.out.println("Enter three integers to form a triangle:");
       side1 = keyboard.nextInt();
       side2 = keyboard.nextInt();
       side3 = keyboard.nextInt();
       yourTriangle.displaySortedNumbers(side1,side2,side3);
       yourTriangle.displayType(side1,side2,side3);
       yourTriangle.perimeter(side1,side2,side3);
 }
```

Comment: It says that it cannot find symbol - variable YourTriangle

Comment: check the spellings.
Probably you have entered "Y"ourTriangle instead of "y"ourTriangle